# Beginner's question about shortcodes

Tags: shortcode

I know i'll get bombarded for this question but the truth is I researched and found nothing.

I'm not a WP expert or anything, i just found my ways to design WP themes. But there is something i never got straight.

***WHY IN HECK SHORT-CODES DON'T WORK FOR ME.***

When i mean shortcodes i mean the ones provided by a plugin, not created by myself what it makes it probably dumber.

**Example:**

I write in a page or a post:

```
[audio src="http://my_url.com/my_track.mp3"]
```

I see the audio controls in the WP editor, but in the browser i see the text, not the audio.

**2nd example:**

I just tried to use a WPForms shortcode in order to display a contact form....
I see the text, not what the shortcode should be doing.

Up to this point my solution if I need to run a shortcode is creating a page/post template and do:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[My_shortcode]'); ?>
```

Thanks a lot and sorry for the dumbest question.

Comment: what theme are you using, and what is the code in the theme to display the content? do shortcodes work if you switch to the default theme Twenty Seventeen, and if you add the shortcode into the content of a post or static page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like theme issue. Switch to default WordPress theme and check it. I have tested it on WordPress Twenty Seventeen theme.

For testing:

1) Add below code in theme `functions.php`

```
// Sample shortcode [testme]
function testme_cb( $atts ) {
    return 'Working? Maybe.';
}
add_shortcode( 'testme', 'testme_cb' );

// Enable shortcodes in text widgets
add_filter('widget_text','do_shortcode');
```

---

2) Goto `Appearance -> Widgets` and add shortcode `[testme]` in Text Widget.

[image: Shortcode]

---

3) Check it on frontend.

[image: Front End]

Comment: Thanks for your response, the shortcodes works in a default theme, not in mine (image captions for instance).
What could i have done to disable shortocdes in my theme??? or do i have to enable them???

Comment: EDIT: OMG!!! i was using echo get_the_content() instead of the_content()

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the syntax of do_shortcode (here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/ ), and the examples shown on that page.

Also, this page https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API on how to use shortcodes in your plugin.

Comment: But my problem isn't with the do_shortcode in my code editor,  it is using shortcodes in post and pages in the WP dashboard.

Comment: Assuming that the shortcode 'code' is set up properly, then putting [my_short_code] in the post/page text area should work.

Answer (score 0):

`[audio src="http://my_url.com/my_track.mp3"]` add shortcode into the content of a post or page
`<?php echo do_shortcode('[My_shortcode]'); ?>` put code in file `.php` eg:`content.php`,`single-post.php` where you want to display
You should learn how to *make shortcode* and *using shortcode* in wordpress page clearly

Comment: I already know that bud. Read the question again. My problem lays in  the dashboard,   not in php.

Comment: what theme are you using,reading the structure ur themes and please put [yourshortcode] or `do_shortcode` correctly